# Leer un xml y mostrarlo en un listbox

Tags: c#, xml

Lo que quiero es mostrarlo desde un listbox el codigo que os muestro en la imagen perdonar pero no lo puedo poner como codigo porque sino no se muestran las etiquetas. Y quiero mostrar la descripcion y el nombre de la clase.

Codigo del xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<furnidata>
<roomitemtypes>
    <furnitype id="13" classname="shelves_norja">
        <revision>61856</revision>
        <defaultdir>0</defaultdir>
        <xdim>1</xdim>
        <ydim>1</ydim>
        <partcolors>
            <color>#ffffff</color>
            <color>#F7EBBC</color>
        </partcolors>
        <name>Beige Bookcase</name>
        <description>For nic naks and books.</description>
        <adurl/>
        <offerid>5</offerid>
        <buyout>1</buyout>
        <rentofferid>-1</rentofferid>
        <rentbuyout>0</rentbuyout>
        <bc>1</bc>
        <excludeddynamic>0</excludeddynamic>
        <customparams/>
        <specialtype>1</specialtype>
        <canstandon>0</canstandon>
        <cansiton>0</cansiton>
        <canlayon>0</canlayon>
        <furniline>iced</furniline>
    </furnitype>
<roomitemtypes>
<furnidata>
```

Comment: [Aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604330/xml-parsing-read-a-simple-xml-file-and-retrieve-values)

Comment: podrias publicar el xml como texto en lugar de una imagen

Comment: tienes que poner el codigo con identacion para que se muestre ne un bloque de codigo, asi se veran los tag

Comment: cual seria la descripcion y codigo de la clase que mencionas ? porque no veo ningun tag que pareciera representar una lista

Comment: <furnitype id="13" classname="shelves_norja"> quiero mostrar su clase y la descripcion <description>For nic naks and books.</description>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con [linq to xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) para parsear el xml y tomar los datos de los nodos cargando una entidad que puedas asignar el Datasource del listbox

[LINQ To XML Tutorials with Examples](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/564/linq-to-xml-tutorials-examples)

[Basic Queries (LINQ to XML) (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693116.aspx)

lastima que hayas publicado el xml como imagen y ademas sin darle un formato que facilite el analisis de la dependencia de los tags

lo que no veo es que nodo tienes estos codigo que quieres listar en el control

Comment: esque cuando pongo el xml se me borran las tags

Comment: recuerda que debes ponerlo identado con al menos 4 espacio para que tome ese texto como codigo, sino usa la toolbox cuando editas la pregunta para ubicar el xml en un bloque de codigo. Recuerda tambien darle identacion para poder analizarlo mejor

Comment: ok gracias ya cambie el codigo gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vas a tener que crear una clase con los atributos correspondientes que tiene el XML

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

string xml = ("xml");
XmlSerializer xmlConverter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(claseXML));
claseXML datos = (claseXML)xmlConverter.Deserialize(xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo único que quieres es mostrar un archivo XML en un ListBox. Utiliza el siguiente código.
Primero debes leer el archivo XML que necesites.

```
//Aquí pones la ubicación del archivo XML
string pathForXML = "rutaXML/archivo.xml";
//Cargas un fileStream con los siguientes parámetros.
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pathForXML, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
//Creas un streamReader el cuál contiene el XML leído.
StreamReader fileRead = new StreamReader(fileStream);
//Ahora recorremos el archivo leído línea por línea y lo agregamos al listBox
 string line = "";
        while (fileRead.Peek() != -1)
        {
            line = fileRead.ReadLine();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
//No podemos olvidar cerrar los Stream.
fileRead.Close();
fileStream.Close();
```

Así de sencillo lees un archivo XML y te queda con toda la indentación correspondiente.